# Set per request disk io priority

Tags: linux, io

While [ioprio_set](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioprio_set) can be used to set per-process io priority, is it possible to set priority for each read()/write() call?  Suppose the OS I am asking about is Linux.  Thanks.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to set it prior to each `read()`/`write()` call?

Comment: I don't think the IO scheduler would perform well under these conditions.

Comment: Not sure if IO scheduler can perform well under such usage.  A major issue for this approach is if the process is multi-thread, and two threads are doing IO at the same time, then the priority set for the process will be messed up.

Comment: According to LXR: [ioprio.c:61](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.6.4/fs/ioprio.c#L61) and  `set_task_ioprio` function, the ioprio is saved in `io_context` of a task struct (thread descriptor). So it is global property of process (thread) and can't be set for some read/write call.

Comment: @osgx, so if it is thread descriptor, then it is possible to set the priority per thread, is that right?  Do you know how to do it?

Comment: icando, try `IOPRIO_WHO_PROCESS` and check with `ioprio_get`.

Comment: @osgx, but that's for a process, not for a thread.

Comment: @icando, it is for task_struct (source line ioprio.c:100 `ret = set_task_ioprio(p, ioprio);`) which is a thread (when NPTL thread library is used, which has 1:1 user/kernel threads and it is a default in Linux+glibc). And PLEASE, try to find newer man page, e.g. use the original man pages on kernel.org: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/ioprio_set.2.html Wait, Oh... kernel.org pages are outdated too (2008-07-09). There is ioprio_set man from 2012-08-14 (man-pages 3.42): http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/ioprio_set.2.html - it says about threads.

Comment: Just use thread_id instead of process ID (PID). TID of current thread is `tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);` or `pthread_self()`. Or just use `0` instead of PID to change ioprio of current thread.